# How to get the orderBy() to work in the new firebase version in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-redux

This is for a LinkedIn clone.

I have been trying to order my array of posts with the orderBy() method but it isn't being implemented. When I submit my post, it will go into a random order.

The post should go in descending order based on the timestamp. The const q variable should be controlling my order but it isn't even being used.

```
const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')
const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    const postCollection = collection(db, 'posts')
    const q = query(postCollection, orderBy('time', 'desc'))
    console.log(q)
    onSnapshot((postCollection), q, snapshot => (
        setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => (
            {
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            }
        )))
    ))}, [])

const sendPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
        name: 'John Doe',
        description: 'This is a test',
        message: input,
        photoUrl: '',
        time: serverTimestamp()
    },)

    setInput('')
}
```

Those are the two sections that control the posts when the submit button is clicked and the post renders to the page. I render my post by clicking the 'enter' key and it will render like a LinkedIn post.

Comment: How do you render your `posts`? Could you also include it in your question.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question to explain that. I render my post by clicking the 'enter' key and it will render like a LinkedIn post. It goes under the input section into a card like post showing the name, description, and message.